# SQLite NO borra en Cascada

Tags: sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una app Android en Kotlin y tengo una tabla `PERSONS` que contiene personas y otra tabla `FACES` que contiene caras que relaciono con las personas. La idea es que al borrar una entrada de `PERSONS`se borren todas las caras asociadas a ella. Creo las tablas de esta forma:

```
const val SQL_CREATE_PERSONS =
            "CREATE TABLE " + "PERSONS" + "(" +
                    "ID" + " TEXT(100) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "NAME" + " TEXT(50)
                    "); "

    const val SQL_CREATE_FACES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + "FACES" + "(" +
                    "ID" + " TEXT(100) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "PERSON_ID " + "TEXT(100), " +
                    "FOREIGN KEY " + "(PERSON_ID)" + " REFERENCES " +
                    "PERSONS" + "(" +
                    "ID" + ") "+
                    "ON DELETE CASCADE " +
                    "); "
```

No me he olvidado de activar las Foreign Keys que vienen desactivadas por defecto, lo hago en el `onCreate()`:

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    db?.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
    db?.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PERSONS)
    db?.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_FACES)
}
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación y eliminar una entrada de `PERSONS` sus caras siguen estando en la tabla `FACES`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que pude encontrar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890250/on-delete-cascade-in-sqlite3) (versión en inglés), la opción `on delete cascade` no está habilitada por defecto y se debe activar con cada conexión, es decir justo antes de cada ejecución de eliminado o actualización.

Para ello se debe lanzar la siguiente query que activa esta propiedad para la conexión actual.

`PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`

Puedes encontrar más información en el siguiente enlace de la información oficial de SQlite:

[2. Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) (inglés)

En tu caso estas añadiendo este soporte en la query para crear las tablas. Para que funcione el soporte debe de adjuntarse antes de la query de eliminación o actualización.

Comment: Ya indico en la pregunta que en el onCreate lanzo la query que dices

Comment: @IbrahimHernándezJorge has probado a lanzar la query concatenada  `db?.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;" + SQL_CREATE_PERSONS )` ?

Comment: @IbrahimHernándezJorge de todas formas el problema que indicas no reside en la creación si no en la eliminación o actualización, es decir cuando haces la consulta de eliminación o de actualización deberías incluir el soporte a foreign keys.

Comment: Exactamente... hay que incluir el soporte justo cuando se va a realizar la acción de eliminación, lo hago justo antes de iniciar la transacción y me funciona. Añádela a la respuesta y la daré por válida. Muchas gracias!